# Playing video through URL of Youtube in Android

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview

I want to play video through URL of YouTube Using `VideoView` in Android. Please help me.

Comment: Provide us details, code, exception. Saludos

Comment: Search ExoPlayer for android  on google.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
waitSign = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
waitSign.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
MediaController contorls = new MediaController(this);
contorls.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(contorls);
String url = "http://www.somedomain.com/samplevideo.mp4";
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
videoView.start();
```

remember to put the extension on the file name